# interface for entity framework context

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, interface

I have two implementation of context providers and I know there will be more to follow.
I would like to create interface to work for those entities in generic.

```
public class TDataProvider
    {
        public TEntities GetDataContext()
        {
            return new TTEntities();
        }
    }

public class TDataProvider
    {
        public TEntities GetDataContext()
        {
            return new TTEntities();
        }
    }
```

I want to use the interface that is mplemeneted in each case such as
But how do I implement followin inteface over the entity model generated by ADO.NET Entity Data Model?

```
public class IGetDataContext
    {
        T GetDataContext();
    }
```

Comment: The data context is a dependency, so use an IoC container rather than an interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating interface on context I have created data access classes responsible for actions and created unit test against that.

Its the best I could think of.